# Spring Security's @PreAuthorize on type level can not be overridden on method level

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to protect a Controller with the `@PreAuthorize` annotation at type level and try to override that behavior by annotating some methods with a different `@PreAuthorize`. The Problem is however, that Spring is evaluating the method annotation first (grants access) and is then evaluating the class annotation (denies access).

Is there any way to reverse that order? I couldn't figure it out yet.

Edit:

On the method level, I want to grant access to non-registered Users only:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderCreateEntity(ModelMap model) {
    return userService.renderCreateEntity(model);
}
```

The standard for this Controller however, should be to allow fully authenticated users only:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
public class UserController { [...] }
```

When debug-stepping through the app, I see that `isAnonymous()` is evaluated first and then `isFullyAuthenticated()` thus resulting in an grant of access right and immediately denying access again.

Comment: Which version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: Everything spring is 3.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for all your replys.
The answer however, was something totally different :)

I put this here in case anyone else has the same problems.

I registered a custom validator in an `@InitBinder` annotated method. This binding method is called AFTER the method call requested on the controller. And since this binding method was not annotated with `@PreAuthorize`, the request was denied.

The solution was to annotate the binding method like this:

```
@InitBinder
@PreAuthorize("permitAll")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

And then, the method calls from my OP evaluated like expected.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not that you need to change the order of grant and deny. The problem is simple that that method level annotations *override* the class level annotations.

[`PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource` Java Doc:](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.html)

> Annotations may be specified on classes or methods, and method-specific annotations will take precedence.

The concrete implementation of this logic is done in the method `findAnnotation` of class `PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource`. (Unfortunately this method is private.)

So you can write your own [`MethodSecurityMetadataSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/method/MethodSecurityMetadataSource.html), if you have a look at the code of `PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource`, you will see how easy it is.

*But one warning at the end: the end: difficult task is not rewriting the method, the difficult task is to "inject" the new `MethodSecurityMetadataSource` into the security system. I belive you can not do it with the spring security namespace configuration, so you need to replace spring security namespace by explicit bean declaration.*

Comment: I actually _WANT_ the method level annotation to override the class level annotation. But the method level annotation is evaluated first and class level second so that the class level annotation actually overrides the method's annotation. I Will edit some example into my question.

Comment: From my testing, that is not true anymore.  If you have a class level and method level security annotation (either @Secured or @PreAuthorized), they both get run.  If the method level annotation is more restrictive, this is just fine.  If it is less restrictive, then it doesn't work.  I ended up splitting my less restrictive methods out into another controller.